# Calling DbExtensions.Load ends method pre-maturely

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 with WinForms, and I'm simply following the [Databinding with WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076) tutorial on MSDN's Entity Framework website.  I changed the Category class to have a SortId so I could store the sorted order:

```
public class Category
{
    private readonly ObservableListSource<Product> _products =
            new ObservableListSource<Product>();

    public Category(int pSortId = 0)
    {
        Name = "New Category";
        SortId = pSortId;
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortId { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableListSource<Product> Products { get { return _products; } }
}
```

However, after adding the SortId, the application stopped displaying the categories in the DataGridView.  By stepping through the debugger and adding debug statements in the OnLoad method, I found that when the call to _context.Categories.Load() is made, that method stops execution prematurely which means the categoryBindingSource is never assigned a datasource.

_context.Categories.Load() is called here (exactly like in [the tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076) mentioned above)

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _context = new ProductContext();
        _context.Categories.Load();
        this.categoryBindingSource.DataSource =
            _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
```

**Question:** Does anyone know why the Load method is doing this?  (It's [DbExtensions.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Load%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true))

If needed, the ProductContext class (also unmodified from the tutorial) is:

```
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Category does not look like a Method here. It is a `class`. Maybe you should include the code that is actually not working (the one that you are trying to debug)

Comment: Sorry, I hoped someone would be familiar with, or people would have the time to look at what's in the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I did say "method" when I meant class.  For now I got around this by splitting the Category constructor so one is truly paramaterless (although I'd assume `Category(int pSortId = 0)` counts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, I won't mark it as the answer yet because this would be more helpful if someone can elaborate more on what is going on behind the scenes

In short, I told Visual Studio to break for any exception (Debug > Exceptions > Check everything under thrown) and found an InvalidOperationException thrown somewhere in external code with the message "The class 'EFWinForms.Category' has no parameterless constructor."

Using this advice, I split the constructor of the Category class as follows:

```
public Category() : this(0) { }

public Category(int pSortId)
{
    Name = "New Category";
    SortId = pSortId;
}
```

My assumption is that the DbExtensions.Load method caught that exception and killed the thread which seems rather odd but I have no way of proving it.